# Непонятная работа UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, дата

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-11-02 00:59:00');
1225601940

select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-11-02 01:00:00');
1225605600

select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-11-02 01:00:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-11-02 00:59:00')
3660
```

Но UNIX_TIMESTAMP возвращает результат в секундах, почему разница 3660 секунд если должно быть 60?

Comment: Если это time zone как избавиться от такого эффекта?

Comment: [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19752) все в норме

Comment: я думаю это какая-то таймзона на удаленном сервере у которой переход на зимнее время  в ноябре

Comment: Да, дело в временной зоне. Сам [сталкивался с таким](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505133/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-strtotime-%D0%B8-time-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), только в др. контексте. Второй Timestamp возвращает время с учётом перевода времени на час.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

> The server interprets `date` as a **value in the current time zone**
>   and converts it to an internal value in UTC. <sup>emphasize mine</sup>

то есть `2008-11-02 01:00:00` это не UTC время и поэтому значение `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` зависит от часового пояса, используемого базой данных (по умолчанию совпадает с поясом, используемым системной временно́й зоной). Часовой пояс может меняться, например, из-за перехода с летнего времени на стандартное ([как упомянул @alexander barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523238/23044)), местное время может прыгнуть на час назад, что увеличивает разницу в данном случае (из двух повторяющихся значений местного времени, выбрано более позднее).

[image: часы назад переведены]

Пример, который явно смещение от UTC показывает (на Питоне):

```py
>>> import pendulum  # $ pip install pendulum
>>> dt = pendulum.create(2008, 11, 2, 0, 59, tz='America/New_York')
>>> dt.timestamp()
1225601940.0
>>> dt.add(seconds=3660)
<Pendulum [2008-11-02T01:00:00-05:00]>
>>> dt.add(seconds=60)
<Pendulum [2008-11-02T01:00:00-04:00]>
```

Видно, что моменты времени `+00:01:00` и `+01:01:00` в будущее имеют одинаковое местное время `1am`, но разные часовые пояса (с летнего на зимнее время переход произошёл):

```py
>>> dt.add(seconds=60).tzname()
'EDT'
>>> dt.add(seconds=3660).tzname()
'EST'
```

Answer (score 3):

дата 2008/11/02 — это второе воскресенье ноября, которое в [некоторых странах](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country#Daylight_Saving_Time_rules_as_of_2016) (например, в канаде) является датой перевода часов с летнего на зимнее время (чаще всего именно в час ночи).

выбором подобной временно́й зоны на сервере, где выполнялись указанные команды, и можно объяснить разницу в 61 минуту **реального** времени (измеряемого, в случае [*unix time stamp*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), секундами, прошедшими с полуночи первого января 1970 года) между двумя временны́ми отметками `2008-11-02 01:00:00` и `2008-11-02 00:59:00`.