# Почему strtotime() и time() дают разное время?

Tags: php, время

Сразу приведу пример кода:

```
$time1 = strtotime('+1 week');
$time2 = time() + 3600*24*7;

var_dump($time1);
var_dump($time2);

echo PHP_EOL;

var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time1));
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time2));
```

Вот полученные результаты:

```
int(1459164441)
int(1459168041)

string(19) "2016-03-28 12:27:21"
string(19) "2016-03-28 13:27:21"
```

Т.е. разница ровно час.

Случайно наткнулся, проверял чего тест стал падать, там дата проверялась.

Интересно, что вчера и позавчера, неделю и месяц назад возвращаемое время было абсолютно одинаковым!

**UPD:** Временная зона установлена "Europe/London".

Comment: А если подумать?

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо за наводку) Правильно ли я ответил?

Comment: У меня кстати ваш код дает одинаковое время, совпадающее часами с текущим локальным. Файлы временных зон последней версии. Посмотрите еще что вам дает strtotime('now'). по идее сейчас пока нет перевода стрелок время должно быть одинаковым. с другой стороны, time должна давать секунды с 1970 по UTC а перевод секунд в дату идет на основании установок часового пояса

Comment: Хотя судя по всему в России перехода не будет на летнее. его отменили и обратно пока не вернули. Шли разговоры что хотят чуть ли не во второе воскресенье марта сделать переход. но оно уже прошло ...

Comment: @Mike В коде временная зона установлена "Europe/London". Если поменять на "Europe/Minsk", то время совпадает с текущим локальным и возвращаемое время одинаковое в обоих случаях. В общем полагаю дело в переводе времени.

Comment: @Ипатьев ping..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В ночь с субботы на воскресенье 27 марта часы переводятся на час назад. Временная зона была установлена "Europe/London".

Т.к. сегодня стукнуло 21 марта, то через неделю уже будет 28 марта. И соответственно время `strtotime('+1 week')` уже выдаёт результат с учётом перевода времени на час назад.

У нас в Беларуси уже отменили перевод на летнее/зимнее время. В России тоже. На временной зоне "Europe/Minsk" и "Europe/Moscow" возвращаемое время одинаковое в обоих случаях.

```
$time1 = strtotime('+1 week');
$time2 = time() + 3600*24*7;
```

В общем, проблема различий во времени связана с переводом времени на час для указанной временной зоны "Europe/London".

Функция `strtotime` учитывает часовой пояс, а `time` - нет, возвращает unix-timestamp.